# Error importing transaction: Transaction(InvalidChainId) in Private POA

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, metamask, proof-of-authority

### Problem

I am trying to send some transactions to my private chain, and all transactions are getting failed. I am receiving this error:

`Error importing transaction: Transaction(InvalidChainId)`

### Environment

I am starting a private chain and defined `networkID` in the genesis file inside `params` as:

`"networkID" : "0xB8A081"`

While starting the node, I am specifying the networkID in the toml file as

`[network]
id = 12099713`

After restarting everything, I reconnect metamask to my RPC and then send transaction using remix and metamask.

Comment: Did this work? Im getting same issue when syncing  : Error(Transaction(InvalidChainId)

Comment: @blockwala Try using a different browser or reinstalling metamask, this issue may be caused because metamask stores chainID in its cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the chainId in your genesis files (Use decimal notation) and this format

Format example:

```
"networkID":123
```

(Use no spaces or Quotations "" for chainId)

In *toml* file:

```
[network]
id = 123
```

It worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

If transactions were imported from another chain, it may fail due to Ethereum reply-protection feature that prevents using Ethereum Classic transactions to work on Ethereum.